# Scrapy crawlspider solution for a local site

Tags: python, scrapy

I created a sample site with 5 pages like this:

```
index.html
  info.html
  countries.html
    france.html
    germany.html
```

Index page has links to info and countries. countries has links to France and Germany. France and Germany has some `p` tags I want to scrape.

I run a simple web server to host this site on `http://localhost:8080`.

I created a scrapy project with a crawl spider as below. What I like to see is scrapy start crawling all the links in the starting from the index. I will create an item class, loaders etc properly to scrape the data but I can't get scrapy to crawl by following the links.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class ServerSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "server"
    allowed_domains = ["localhost:8080"]
    start_urls = [
        'http://localhost:8080/index.html'
    ]

    rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='.*'), follow=True, callback='parse_links')
    ]

    def parse_links(self, response)
        print '>>> parse_links'
```

How should I modify the spider?

Comment: What is the output you are getting, Shelly? Also, what if you set `allowed_domains = ["localhost"]`?

Comment: Changing allowed_domains from 'localhost:8080' to 'localhost' made it work. I see scrapy following the links. Thanks!